# Fill C# String/PWideChar by Delphi DLL (x64)

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-10.3-rio

up front, this is my first post/question, so please be gentle

I'm having a problem with a Delphi (10.3) dll, which is supposed to fill a string, or more precisely a PWideChar.

The strange thing about this, is that it works when compiling 32 bit, but not with 64 bit?

As stated in the title, the dll function is meant to be called by a c# app, but due to Delphi Debugger issues I'm testing the function using a VCL App.

So here is my DLL Code:

```
function GetName(var id: integer;  var name : PWideChar) : integer;  stdcall;
var     
  tempstr : string;
  test : PwideChar;
begin
  tempstr := GetNameByID(id) // this just writes the name to a local variable
  name := PWideChar(tempstr); //this throws a Access violation in System.Move
  result := 0; 
end;
```

And the Calling App Code:

```
function Getname(var id: integer;  var name : PWideChar)  : integer;  stdcall; external '<dllname>.dll';

procedure TryGetName;
var 
  returnedName : string;
  temp : PWideChar;
 tempint : Integer;
Begin
  returnedName:= 'here is som content which is definitly longer then the name to return';
  temp := PWideChar(returnedName);
  tempint := 0;
  GetName(tempint, temp);
end;
```

So this works fine in 32 Bit, but in 64 bit the name assignment in the DLL throws a Access violation in the function System.Move, where the NativeInt is analyzed.

So far i tried different Variants like

```
StrLCopy
StringToWideChar
```

or moving the string to a local variable. It seems like, the DLL has no Access to the WideChar Array the Host app is creating, but i dont understand why this depends on the compile architecture?

I obviously need to use PWideChar, since the name should be written to a C# string, which is passed by *ref* or *out*.

Does anybody know why this would behave like it does?

**EDIT: @Remy Lebau: you are absolutly correct, this code wouldn't even compile because I passed 0 as Var, I just wrote it down like this because I was lazy while breaking down my code to the essentials. i adjusted the code accordingly**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DLL function is taking parameters by `var` reference, which means it is allowed to modify the caller's variables (that is not necessary for the `id` parameter since the function does not change its value).

The function is merely re-assigning its `name` parameter (thus changing the caller's `PWideChar` variable) to point at a different memory address.  It does not actually try to write anything into the memory that is being pointed at, so there is no way you could be getting any error from `Move()` since it should not be getting called to begin with.

If `Move()` is actually being called, then the code you have shown here is not the actual code you are using in your real project.  In fact, the code you have shown here should not even compile, as you cannot pass a `0` literal to a `var` parameter, like you are doing.

That being said, even if the code compiled and ran without crashing, do note that the DLL function you have shown is setting the caller's `PWideChar` variable to point at memory that gets freed when the function exits.  That will cause problems if the caller tries to read anything from that memory afterwards.

It sounds like you want the caller to allocate memory that the DLL function fills with data.  If so, then the code you have shown is all wrong for that.  Try something more like this instead:

```pascal
function GetName(id: integer; name: PWideChar; namesize: integer): integer; stdcall;
var     
  tempstr: UnicodeString;
  size: Integer;
begin
  tempstr := GetNameByID(id);
  size := Length(tempstr) + 1;
  if (name <> nil) and (namesize >= size) then
  begin
    Move(PWideChar(tempstr)^, name^, size * SizeOf(WideChar));
    Dec(size);
  end;
  Result := size;
end;
```

Then your VCL app can do this:

```pascal
function Getname(id: integer; name: PWideChar; namesize: integer): integer; stdcall; external '<dllname>.dll';

procedure TryGetName;
var 
  returnedName: string;
begin
  SetLength(returnedName, 100);
  if GetName(0, PWideChar(returnedName), Length(returnedName) + 1) <= Length(returnedName) then
  begin
    // use returnedName as needed...
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
function Getname(id: integer; name: PWideChar; namesize: integer): integer; stdcall; external '<dllname>.dll';

procedure TryGetName;
var 
  returnedName: string;
  size: Integer;
begin
  size := GetName(0, nil, 0);
  SetLength(returnedName, size - 1);
  GetName(0, PWideChar(returnedName), size);
  // use returnedName as needed...
end;
```

Your C# app can then do this:

```cs
[DllImport("<dllname>.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int GetName(int id, StringBuilder name, int namesize);

void TryGetName()
{
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(100);
    int size = GetName(0, buf, buf.Capacity + 1);
    if (size <= buf.Capacity)
    {
        string returnedName = buf.ToString(0, size);
        // use returnedName as needed...
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```cs
[DllImport("<dllname>.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int GetName(int id, StringBuilder name, int namesize);

void TryGetName()
{
    int size = GetName(0, nil, 0);
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(size - 1);
    size = GetName(0, buf, size);
    string returnedName = buf.ToString(0, size);
    // use returnedName as needed...
}
```

---

That being said, you could instead have the DLL allocate a new string to return to the caller, instead of using an output parameter, eg:

```pascal
function GetName(id: integer): PWideChar; stdcall;
var     
  tempstr : UnicodeString;
  size: Integer;
begin
  tempstr := GetNameByID(id);
  size := (Length(tempstr) + 1) * SizeOf(WideChar);
  Result := PWideChar(CoTaskMemAlloc(size));
  if Result <> nil then
    Move(PWideChar(tempstr)^, Result^, size);
end;
```

And then your VCL app can do this:

```pascal
function Getname(id: integer): PWideChar; stdcall; external '<dllname>.dll';

procedure TryGetName;
var 
  returnedName: PWideChar;
begin
  returnedName := GetName(0);
  if returnedName <> nil then
  try
    // use returnedName as needed...
  finally
    CoTaskMemFree(returnedName);
  end;
end;
```

And your C# app can do this:

```cs
[DllImport("<dllname>.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern string GetName(int id);

void TryGetName()
{
    string returnedName = GetName(0);
    // use returnedName as needed...
}
```

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvienences, you are right about both your assumtptions stating that the code is not exactly the one i tried. This was caused by lazyness on my side. GetNameById acutally wasn't a function to begin with but a mere member field access. I didn't keep in mind that this would change behaviour. 

On the grander scale, thanks for your insight on the usage of PWideChar and the passed parameter details, I will try your provided solution and report back